Making exception in permissions (linux)
I've encountered a very annoying problem recently. I want to share a folder named 'html' to 'users' group with full control over it (rwx), but there is one file in that folder, named 'index.html', that I don't want any user other than root to write to that file (r-x). How can I do that?
After these changes:
$ su root
$ chgrp -R users html/
$ chmod -R 775 html/
$ cd html/
$ chgrp root index.html

any user can write to 'index.html', and even permanently delete it. I don't want it to happen, so how can I secure that only file? Can I even do that? How does this anomaly exists?

If you want to no one can edit it also root user(readonly), you can do this as a root
chattr +i html/index.html

And if you want to revert it(access to write), you must run this
chattr -i html/index.html


I fixed this issue as setting that is difference folder and file 's group
First, change the group of the  html  folder to  users :
su root
  chgrp -R users html/

And then, Set the permissions for the  html  folder to give the  users  group full control (read, write, execute) and others no permissions:
chmod -R 770 html/

And Change the group of the  index.html  file back to  root :
chgrp root html/index.html

And Set the permissions for the  index.html  file to allow only the owner (root) to read and execute it, while the group and others have no permissions:
chmod 440 html/index.html

I hope this guide can help you.

Thank you for this guide, but xirehat gave me the answer that is more what I want to do with the file. I want anyone to access the file (r-x), but only root can modify its contents. xirehat's answer does not let anyone, even root, modify the file, but actually it's not a problem anyway, because root can always change group to root and then "unchattr" the file.
